# Cakephp how I will write coalesce in query builder on sum?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have postgres query like below

```
coalesce(sum(SUMMARY_COINS.get_count),0) as total
```

I am trying to convert in cakephp query builder

```
$query = $query->select([
    'total' => $query->func()->coalesce($query->func()->sum('c.get_count'),0)
]
```

Getting error , How I will apply `coalesce` in query builder for make isnull zero in sum?

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please include the full error message in your questions (and ideally also the related stacktrace), even if the problem might be obvious for people familiar with CakePHP - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the API documentation, the `coalesce()` function expects an array that holds the function arguments!

Also note that you need to pass corresponding type information unless you want your scalar values to be bound as strings:

```php
$query->func()->coalesce(
    [$query->func()->sum('c.get_count'), 0],
    // the first type is `null` because expressions (`sum()`) are not being bound
    [null, 'integer']
)
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder::coalesce()](https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#coalesce())**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions > Custom Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#custom-functions)**